# How to sort on the basis of 2nd element if there is a tie on first in vector of tuples

Tags: c++11, stdvector, stdtuple

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
vector < tuple <ll,ll,ll> > a;
int main()
{
    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    ll id,z,p,l,c,s,newz;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>id>>z>>p>>l>>c>>s;
        newz=p*50+l*5+c*10+s*20;
        a.push_back(make_tuple(z-newz,id,newz));
    }
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        tie(ignore,id,z)=a[i];
        cout<<id<<" "<<z<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- I want the sort on the vector to happen on the basis of first element of the tuple but only when there is a tie then the smallest of the second element of the tuple must be chosen to order the elements with the same first value.
- Also specify what should be done, if at the time of a tie the order should be maintain on the basis of greater element of the second element of the tuple(instead of the first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom function as a third parameter sorted my way out perfectly.

```
bool cmp( tuple <ll,ll,ll>  const &s, tuple <ll,ll,ll>  const &r)
{
    if(get<0>(s)==get<0>(r))
    {
        return (get<1>(s))>(get<1>(r));
    }
    else
    return (get<0>(s))<(get<0>(r));
}
sort(a.begin(),a.end(),cmp);// Call to sort will change like this.
```